# Unravel table links

Tags: data, table

What are the relationship links (field names and any other tables used to link) between the four tables below:

Account Opportunity Quote User

Thanks you for any help

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you simply access your org, go to setup, quick find the Schema Builder, clear all objects from the diagram ("Clear All" option at the top of the object list on the left), select "Standard Objects" then check Account, Opportunity, Quote and User. This will show you a graphical presentation of the schema including the relationships as links.

[image]

It's a good way to explore the schema.

You can also look at the online documentation (e.g. [for Opportunity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=opp_fields.htm&type=5)) for specific details around the fields and relationships.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Phil W, the bit I am struggling with mainly is where the field says Lookup relationship, e.g. Quote has a lookup relationship to Account. If I could see the code of how the relationship is made I can use the same logic. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. Most data relationships are initialized during the creation of the object, so (as an example) when a user creates a Quote they do so through the UI and set the Account for which the quote is being created. Some quick actions will present the object creation form with certain fields already populated - so, for example, you might have a quick action on Account called "Create Quote". Here this might fill the quote's account lookup using the current Account's identity.